# Como só submeter o formulário se o campo estiver preenchido

Tags: javascript, formulário

No formulário abaixo, executei testes com os campos em branco, mas a função `validate` não parece ser chamada.

Além disso, o programa PHP (`if(isset($_POST['register']))`) só irá rodar se o evento `onsubmit` (que chama a função JavaScript) retornar `true`? De qualquer maneira o script não deveria retornar um alerta (independente de o programa rodar ou não)?

```js
function validate(form) {
    fail  = validateForename(form.f_name.value);
    if (fail == "") { return true; }
    else { alert('fail'); return false; }
};
 
function validateForename(field)
{
    if (field == "") { return "No Forename was entered.\n"; }
    else {
    return ""; }
};
```

```html
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="Nome"> 
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" onsubmit="return validate(this)" class="aa-browse-btn">
</form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $c_fname = $_POST['f_name'];
        $insert_c = "insert into customers (customer_fname) 
                    values ('$c_fname'')";
?>
```

Comment: onsubmit é um atributo do form não do input submit. Já que aparentemente você tem um script php também, crie um <form></form> e coloque o seu submit como um atributo dele. Além disso, tem outros erros menores que você vai precisar corrigir.

Comment: obrigado por responder. Nao está claro, eh a nivel experimental.

Answer (score 2):

O evento de `submit` é referente ao formulário (`form`), não ao `input`, conforme consta na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event):

> *Note that the submit event fires on the `<form>` element itself, and not on any `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` inside it. (**Forms are submitted, not buttons**.)*

Sendo assim, você deve colocar o `onsubmit` no `form`, não no `input`:

```js
function validate(form) {
    if (form.f_name.value !== "") return true;
    alert('fail');
    return false;
};
```

```html
<form action="arquivo.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="Nome"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="aa-browse-btn"> 
</form>
```

Repare também que não precisa de duas funções para validar, uma é o suficiente: se o valor não for vazio, retorna `true`, senão, exibe o alerta e retorna `false` (e esse trecho não precisa necessariamente estar em um bloco `else`, pois se entrar no `if` o `return` já sai da função).

Enfim, se o `validate` retornar `true`, o formulário é submetido e enviado para  `arquivo.php`, que é o que eu coloquei no `action`. Se retornar `false`, ele não é submetido.

---

Outra forma de obter o mesmo comportamento é usando [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). O código fica ligeiramente diferente, mas a ideia é a mesma, só submeter o formulário se o campo estiver preenchido:

```js
function validate(event) {
    if (event.target.f_name.value === "") {
        alert('fail');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

```html
<form id="formulario" action="arquivo.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="Nome"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="aa-browse-btn"> 
</form>
```

A diferença é que agora eu uso `addEventListener` para registrar o evento de `submit`, e  [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar que o formulário seja submetido.

Outra diferença é que a função `validate` agora recebe um [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), e o formulário é obtido acessando o [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) desse `Event`.